# c# MongoDB driver: FindOneAndUpdate how to know if it has found a document?

Tags: c#, mongodb

So I'm using the MongoDB driver to update an object field value in the database if the object exist.

```
 IMongoDatabase db = _mongoClient.GetDatabase(DataBase);
 IMongoCollection<Evento> collection = db.GetCollection<Evento>(str_collection);

 collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
     e => e._id == eventoId &&
     e._visitantes.Any(v => v._empresa == empresa &&
         v._nombre == nombre &&
         v._apellidos == apellidos),
     Builders<Evento>.Update.Set(e => e._visitantes[-1]._asistido, true));
```

My question is: how I know that the object has found in the database? I have seen the documentation and I didn't found anything.

In the case it doesn't exist, I don't want to create a new object, only I want to know if an object has found to change the value.

Thanks.

Comment: Check result returned by FindOneAndUpdate, in console Mongo returns how many objects affected, probably result will containt this info.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`FindOneAndUpdate`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_FindOneAndUpdate__1.htm) will return a document. You can configure whether this is the old or the updated version of the document by using the [`ReturnDocument`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_FindOneAndUpdateOptions_2_ReturnDocument.htm) property of [`FindOneAndUpdateOptions`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOneAndUpdateOptions_2.htm). Setting `ReturnDocument` to `ReturnDocument.Before` ensures that the document that gets returned is the document that existed *before* the update, which would be `null` if no document existed. Here's an example:

```
var documentBefore = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
    filterDefinition,
    updateDefinition,
    new FindOneAndUpdateOptions { ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.Before });

if (documentBefore != null)
{
    // The document already existed and was updated.
}
else
{
    // The document did not exist and was inserted.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The mongoose [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) states in the **Options** section:

> **Options:**
>
> - ...
> - upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.
> - ...

There should an `upsert` parameter, which, if set to true, will create a new object if none was found. However, this defaults to false, so your call should not create a new database entry.

I would assume that the `C# driver` should behave identically. If not, you could set the `Upsert` parameter to false, see [here](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_FindOneAndUpdateOptions_2.htm)

Comment: Why would the official C# driver behave identically to a third party ORM implementation?!